# How do I extend InstantUI?

Tags: codenameone

I will like to extend InstantUI to be able to include images, maps, lists, videos and embedded propertybusinessobjects in the generated UI. Where should I start and what components/modules/interfaces/classes do I need to implement or extend?

Answer (score 1):

Right now `InstantUI` is still in-extensible and in the proof of concept stages. We're working on improving it and the idea of pluggability is indeed a good direction.

Right now the logic is very simple and coded into a single method.